# How can I make Gulp process the same file twice?

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

I'm using gulp to quickly concatenate a bunch of sql files together (don't ask).

```js
gulp.task('sqlConcat', ['copy'], function () {
    var sqlFiles = [
        'GenericHeader.sql',
        'Sql1.sql',
        'GenericHeader.sql',
        'Sql2.sql',
        'Sql3.sql'
    ];
    gulp.src(sqlFiles)
        .pipe(wrap('-- \n-- <%= file.relative %> \n-- \n\n<%= contents %>'))
        .pipe(concat('ConcatenatedSql.sql'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('release'))
});
```

The issue I have is that gulp only processes the GenericHeader.sql file once, and ignores it on the second occurrence.

Is there a way to override the default behavior and make gulp include GenericHeader.sql for a second time?

Comment: I don't think so. Just create another task that runs after this to wrap that file alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a stream queue with merge:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var wrap = require('gulp-wrap');
var merge = require('merge2');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return merge(
        gulp.src(['GenericHeader.sql', 'Sql1.sql']),
        gulp.src(['GenericHeader.sql', 'Sql2.sql', 'Sql3.sql'])
    )
    .pipe(wrap('<%= contents %>'))
    .pipe(concat('concat.sql'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

With that you do not pass multiple files to your process (which won't work), but multiple streams (which are different)

Comment: Bingo. That worked and provides good clarity on how the files logically group together, thanks!